# Kafka: multiple consumers in the same group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have a Kafka cluster with several topics spread over several partitions. Also, I have a cluster of applications act as clients for Kafka. Each application in that cluster has a client that is subscribed to a same set of topics, which is identical over the whole cluster. Also, each of these clients share same Kafka group ID.

Now, speaking of commit mode. I really do not want to specify offset manually, but I do not want to use autocommit either, because I need to do some handing after I receive my data from Kafka.

With this solution, I expect to occur "same data received by different consumers" problem, because I do not specify offset before I do reading (consuming), and I read data concurrently from different clients.

Now, my question: what are the solutions to get rid of multiple reads? Several options coming to my mind:

1) Exclusive (sequential) Kafka access. Until one consumer committed read, no other consumers access Kafka.
2) Somehow specify offset before each reading. I do not even know how to do that with assumption that read might fail (and offset will not be committed) - we gonna need some complicated distributed offset storage.

I'd like to ask people experienced with Kafka to recommend something to achieve behavior I need.

Answer (score 1):

Every partition is consumed only by one client - another client with the same group ID won't get access to that partition, so concurrent reads won't occur...

Comment: This is only guaranteed in an ideal situation where everything is running smooth. However, if one consumer exceeds poll time limit while processing records, the broker will assign the partition to the different consumer in the same group and offsets will be reprocessed.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I maybe misunderstood the question.

Comment: Assuming fault scenarios are possible, there is no way to reliably prevent double-reads, right?

Comment: Possible only if you manage offsets on your end like in a file or a key-value store, whichever you prefer.